# Symfony app not sending mails (mails not being delivered)

Tags: ubuntu, symfony1

I am running Symfony 1.3.2 on Ubuntu 9.10

I have set up a test action to send an email to my self. The action is executed allright, and there are no errors, however the mail never arrives.

I have tried the same action for this website, on an XP machine, and the mail gets delivered correctly. I have set up my php.ini correctly (i.e. as per the Symfony docs). However, the mail fails to arrive.

Any suggestions on what I may have overlooked/ how I may fix this?

Comment: Are there any records in your maillog for any activity? Can you send mail using just the PHP mail() function? That would be a good place to start. I'm not familiar with Swiftmailer which I believe is the mailer in sf1.3, but try also configuring that to point at different SMTP servers to help isolate if it's a problem with your localhost sendmail.

Comment: I recall having the same problem on my local dev system, decided to do this instead for testing: (http://www.metulo.net/how-to-send-an-email-with-symfony-and-gmail) and postpone the fix till I move to testing on an external server. The gmail route works for me.

Comment: Raise: I think you are on the right track. I suspect that its because I'm using sendmail on Ubuntu, and my SMTP server on XP, thats where the prob is coming from. Too busy with other things at the moment, to investigate this any further though, until about a couple of weeks time

Comment: Okay. Please keep the post updated - especially if you have an answer. A recently deleted comment/answer mentioned `mailer.yml` as a point of interest, but this is only valid for sf1.0. For your situation, you may need to point Swiftmailer (via its config) at your SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed a mail server on your server and/or configured it correctly?

Also although unlikely if you're running exactly the same site on your XP machine, are you sure your Symfony app has its delivery strategy set to realtime rather than spool? If so your messages may be being queued. [More with Symfony: E-Mails](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/04-Emails).

Comment: Steve: thanks, this I copied the files over from my XP machine to the Ubuntu box, so all the configurations are EXACTLY the same. Regarding php.ini, I had to modify it so that it uses sendmail instead of the SMTP service provided by my ISP. I suspect the problem is related to this part of the configuration